# Display data from ArrayList in android from one activity to another activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I would like to show car specification information when button click. Illustration enclosed. The data from array list. So far my code :

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final CardViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Car car = listCar.get(position);
        Glide.with(holder.itemView.getContext())
                .load(car.getFoto())
                .apply(new RequestOptions().override(350, 550))
                .into(holder.imgFoto);
        holder.tvCarName.setText(car.getName());
        holder.tvCarSpecs.setText(car.getSpecs());

        holder.btnSpec.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent detailCar= new Intent(v.getContext(), DetailActivity.class);
                v.getContext().startActivity(detailPage);
            }
        });
}
```

[image: Get data from activity to another activity]

DetailActivity code

```
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArrayList<Car> listCar;

    public DetailActivity(ArrayList<Car> list) {
        this.listCar = list;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

         Intent intent = getIntent();
         listElang = (ArrayList<Elang>) intent.getSerializableExtra("DATA");


    }
}
```

Comment: Android Studio IDE has nothing to do with your problem. Please fix your question title and tags.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to make Car class as [parcelable](https://codentrick.com/quickly-create-parcelable-class-in-android-studio/) then you can pass car object to another activity

```
Intent detailCar= new Intent(v.getContext(), DetailActivity.class);
detailCar.putExtra("item",car)
v.getContext().startActivity(detailCar);
```

in DetailActivity just get the object

```
onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
  if(getIntent()!=null && getIntent.getParcelableExtra("item")!=null){
     Car car=(Car)getIntent().getParcelable("item")
  }
}
```

for beginner tutorial check this [link](https://www.sitepoint.com/transfer-data-between-activities-with-android-parcelable/)

Answer (score 0):

To show car specification information when button click, you can use intent to pass data from one activity to another activity .

First of all create a Serializable model class

**Like this:**

```
public class DemoModel implements Serializable{
String name;
String number;

  public DemoModel(String name, String number){
  this.name=name;
  this.number=number;
 }

public String getName(){
  return name;
 }

public void setName(String name){
  this.name=name;
}

public String getNumber(){
  return number;
}

public void setNumber(String number){
  this.number=number;
}
```

}

**OnItemClick**
    ArrayListdatalist;

```
 Intent intent=new Intent(this,FirstActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("car_detail",datalist.get(i));
            startActivity(intent);
```

**SecondActivity**

```
DemoModel cardetail= (DemoModel) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("car_detail");
  Log.e("check_response", ""+cardetail.getName()));
```

Comment: You can also use getParcelableExtra (String name, Class<T> clazz). In your case getParcelableExtra ("car_detail", Class<Car> clazz)